# Google Cloud Sync on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, sync, google-drive

As you know, you can set your online accounts on Ubuntu - **Settings => Online Accounts**

When you add your Google account here, you can mount your Google drive on your ubuntu desktop. Are your files on your Google One account downloaded to your pc too (like on windows)? Or it works directly through cloud?

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I don't have enough space to download all my files for example.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/196635/an-official-google-drive-for-linux-is-here-sort-of-maybe-this-is-all-well-ever-get/):

> These files are not synced offline to your desktop. However, you can browse files, open them, and save them. Your system will automatically upload the modified copy. Any files you add or delete are instantly synchronized back to your Google account, too.